# How to Open an excel file which is saved in one drive or online, through a Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I want to open an excel file saved in one drive shared folder through a windows form application. Currently the application can open a local file.
Is there any option to browse an online file through a windows form application.

To open a local file I used open file dialog.The code is as below.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Excel File to Edit";
    openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xlsx;*.xls";

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        sFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        if (sFileName.Trim() != "")
        {
            readExcel(sFileName);
            richTextBox1.Text = sFileName;
            isOpend = true;
        }
    }
}

private void readExcel(string sFile)
{
    //xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    try
    {
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFile);           // WORKBOOK TO OPEN THE EXCEL FILE.
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Main Sheet"];      // NAME OF THE SHEET.

        for (iRow = 8; iRow <= xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count; iRow++)  // START FROM THE SECOND ROW.
        {
            if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[iRow, 3].value == null)
            {
                break;      // BREAK LOOP.
            }
            else
            {               // POPULATE COMBO BOX.
                comboBox1.Items.Add(xlWorkSheet.Cells[iRow, 3].value);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to look into the OneDrive APIs. That said, this is far too broad and has nothing to do with WinForms

Comment: For the online file purpose, do u have the file URL which you can open via browser or is yr case specifically for Onedrive file access?

Comment: Hi Aluan, One drive is just for an example.. i want to open a excel file which i saved in cloud .

Comment: NitinSingh,I though to put the file path to the variable  sFileName in the code above. but it not works becoz, I cant get the excel work book path instead of path of opened excel workbook.